# Creating an instance of a class existing in a different file(python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I am trying to learn how to change my programs so that they use code from multiple python scripts. I have two scripts (these are big files, so cutting them down to only what's needed)

main.py

```
import pygame
import player #Imports the player.py script
p1 = hero("woody.png",[2,2]) #Creates an instance of hero
```

player.py

```
import pygame
import main

class hero:
    def __init__(self,image,speed):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.speed = speed
        self.pos = self.image.get_rect()
```

Running this gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hero'
```

I'm not quite understanding why it's trying to get an attribute instead of creating an instance. I've tried looking at other examples and how they are solving the problem but when I attempt to apply it to the code above it does not solve my issue.

Comment: ```from player import hero``` ??

Comment: Why are you importing `main` in `player`???

Comment: you are importing player in main and main in player. That usually causes problems as it creates a kind of loop.

Comment: Give us the whole error Traceback. As written, I would expect a `NameError` for `hero`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Athena said above, don't import `main` into `player` and `player` into `main`. This causes a import loop. Just simply import `player` into `main`

Secondly, you must say `player.hero()` if you want to use the class `hero` from the `player` module. Or if you want to just say `hero()`, you can say `from player import*`. This tells python to import all the files from `player` into the namespace `main`.

**Be careful using this though**, as a function or class from your player file may conflict with an already exiting function or class, with the same name.

And as a side note, classes in python general have their first letter capitalized.

here is how your files should look:

**main.py**

```
import pygame
import player #Imports the player.py script
p1 = hero("woody.png",[2,2]) #Creates an instance of hero
```

**player.py**

```
import pygame

class hero:
    def __init__(self,image,speed):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.speed = speed
        self.pos = self.image.get_rect()#.......etc
```

Comment: I don't get why people suggest import *, then have to give a warning. There are two perfectly good (and better) ways of doing it. player.hero() and hero() after importing hero from player. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ ;)

Comment: @JamesMcCormac Well that may be a viable option for him. I'm just giving him a warning. I'll let him choose which works best.

Comment: Well given the OP is having trouble with imports it might be best to suggest the two explicit approaches and ignore the implicit?

Comment: @JamesMcCormac yeah I guess in the end, it might be best to steer him to two explicit approaches, to avoid confusion. But it doesn't hurt to how him more a advanced approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. To import `hero` from another module, you should write `player.hero`, or simply `from player import hero`.
2. Importing `player` in `main` and `main` in `player` would cause "circular references".

---

Here is the modified code:

main.py

```
import pygame
from player import hero # Imports the player.py script

p1 = hero("woody.png",[2,2]) # Creates an instance of hero
```

player.py

```
import pygame    

class hero:
    def __init__(self,image,speed):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.speed = speed
        self.pos = self.image.get_rect()#.....etc
```

Comment: Sorry dude. Didn't mean do edit your question. Thought is was mine.

Comment: @Mr.Python I've approved your edit, so never mind :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Fingers just got ahead of the brain for a second :)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `import main` in player.py and change the last line in main.py to:

```
p1 = player.hero("woody.png",[2,2])
```

**Edit:**
Python does not know what class/function `hero` is. It needs you to tell it hero is a class in the player module. And that's what `player.hero` means.

Also never import one module from another and vice versa. You can get an import loop which is very hard to debug.

Lastly, in python it is common to name a class with a capital letter as `Hero` instead of `hero`.